# How to use javascript filter() to find the all the same grades and save them into another array, to later printing out the names of the students

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to learn how to use filter() using javascript with strings. My idea is to use filter() to find all occurrences that has the same string value in an array and and use those that to print out all the names that has the same grade from another array.

But I have this far only been able to print all the student's name with the respectively grade instead of for example only all names who has grade 'C'.

What I have tried this far is to input the value/grade into a textbox so I should can use that values to be searched for in the array. I have implemented a basic code that should be able to solve my the mission of this code. But nothing happens unless I use a for loop, then it prints all names with their respectively grade. And as far as I have understood from what I have been reading I should not need to use any for loop to get the code to do what I want.

I am feeling stuck.

I assume that it depends on that I have not been able find any examples that uses strings that must much as all I have found this far is example that uses checks string values after their length and not for the conditions I want to make the code for.

I might have missed the information I need, but This far I have not seen anything close to what might help me understand how to solve this problem.

this is the style of information of some source that I have found and everything else I found this far has been very similar to these.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-array-filter](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-array-filter/)
https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-array-filter/

I am not sure if I should show any code or not but here it goes anyway.

```
var studentArray = ["Clara", "Andreas", "Emilio", "Sarah", "Alice", "Victoria", "Thomas", "Roberta"];
var gradeArray = ["A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "C", "E", "E"];

function input() {
    var grade = document.getElementById("grade").value;
    return grade;
}

function getGradesToNames() {
    var filteredArray = gradeArray.filter(input);
    for (var i = 0; i < filteredArray.length; i++){
        document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML += studentArray[i] + " " + filteredArray[i] + "<br/>"; 
    }
}
function print() {
    input();
    getGradesToNames();
}
```

I know I am a complete beginner but I hope someone can help me by guiding me in the right direction.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.filter` won't work well here, at least not *alone*, because once you've filtered one of the arrays, you'll have lost the index of each item that connects it to the item in the other array. If you want to filter, zip the arrays together first, so you have an array of objects with `name` and `grade` properties:

```js
var studentArray = ["Clara", "Andreas", "Emilio", "Sarah", "Alice", "Victoria", "Thomas", "Roberta"];
var gradeArray = ["A", "B", "C", "A", "D", "C", "E", "E"];
const zipped = studentArray.map((name, i) => ({ name, grade: gradeArray[i] }));

function getGradesToNames() {
  zipped
    .filter(({ grade }) => grade === 'C')
    .forEach(({ name, grade }) => {
      document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML += name + " " + grade + "<br/>"; 
    });
}
getGradesToNames();
```

```html
<div id="output2"></div>
```

If the grade to be searched for comes from a variable, like an input, just substitute the `=== 'C'` with a comparison against that variable.

Comment: It was some difference from what I was try to do, thank you for your help even though I see it is a little bit difficult to understand it. And a short question, is this code you wrote part of what is called regular expressions?

Comment: No, there are no regular expressions here.